# Classifying a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

How do I classify the following differential equation?  In particular, is this differential equation "homogeneous?"

> $$(x^3+3y^2)dx-2xydy=0$$

Solving it is not the problem, but I don't know how to recognize it.

Comment: As a general rule, please always type your questions instead of linking to images, especially those which are not hosted on stackexchange servers.  We have no control over if or when your link will no longer be good at which point this question has no benefit to future users.  Please visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to properly type in $\LaTeX$ on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A differential equation is called homogeneous if the sum of powers of variables in each term is constant i.e. each term is in dimensional balance.

As given differential equation: $(x^3+3y^2)dx-2xydy=0 \iff x^3+3y^2-2xy\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

It is clear that sum of powers of (of $x$ & $y$) first (left most) term is $3$ while second & third terms have sum of powers equal to $2$ i.e. sum of powers of each term is not constant (equal).

Hence, the given differential equation is not homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

> first order nonlinear ordinary

first order: because you have $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$ and not $y''$ or $y'''$

nonlinear: because you have $y^2$

Comment: And how do I know about homogeneity?

Comment: if $p(x)y'+q(x)y=\color{red}0$ so it homogeneity else if $p(x)y'+q(x)y=\color{red}{\cos x}$ or it equale to non zero so it is not homogeneity

Comment: that is the other meaning for homogeneity, which, is an overused term especially in DEqns...

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_linear_differential_equations):

Definition. A linear differential equation is called homogeneous if the following condition is satisfied: If $\phi(x)$  is a solution, so is $c \phi(x)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary (non-zero) constant.